# When to use B'' or B''D as a measure of response bias?

Tags: r, bias, signal-detection

Based on information from Macmillan and Creelman's *Detection Theory* (2005) and Pallier's R-code that I found here, [Computing discriminability and bias with the R software](http://www.pallier.org/ressources/aprime/aprime.pdf),
I came up with code to calculate $B^{''}$ (used as a measure of response bias in psychological "yes/no"-experiments). Pallier suggests a diferent measure of bias than Macmillan & Creelman (pp. 100-104, 371).

In the code below, "fa" stands for false alarm rate and "hit" for hit rate.

```
> bpp <- function(hit, fa) {
    a <- ((hit*(1-hit)-fa*(1-fa)) / (hit*(1-hit)+fa*(1-fa)))
    b <- ((fa*(1-fa)-hit*(1-hit)) / (hit*(1-hit)+fa*(1-fa)))
    a[fa>hit] <- b[fa>hit]
    a[fa==hit] <- 0
    a
  }
```

Here is the original $B^{''}_D$ code as provided by Pallier:

```
> bppd <- function(hit,fa) {
    ((1-hit)*(1-fa)-hit*fa) / ((1-hit)*(1-fa)+hit*fa)
  }
```

What is the difference between these two measures of response bias? When is it appropriate to use which?

Comment: I am taking no answers as a sing that I am totally on the wrong track here? Or is the question just too... well, stupid?

Comment: Do you have access to the paper referenced by C. Pallier, [Measuring recognition memory](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1402701)?

Comment: @chl: Yes, I do, if needed, I could forward it by mail...

Comment: I have it too. I though you were asking (in part) about the rationale for using $B^{''}_D$ which looks to be detailed p. 276 of the article.

Comment: Yes, you got that right. But I simply don't understand the explanation given there. Is there a way to explain this to someone who does not have such a firm grasp on maths? ...

Answer (score 1):

Handbook of Human Factors and Ergonomics by Gavriel Salvendy, p. 973-974, cites some other works that recommend to use BppD = Donaldson's one (cited by Pallier). The other code you mention comes from Grier.
Hope it helps.